# keep position of item when insert ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have a ListView.

```dart
 List<int> list = [1,2,3,4,5,6 ... ,100];
 ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          controller: scrollController,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              child: Text('${list[index]}'),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Now my `scrollOffset =0` , `item  =1`
I want insert `[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0]` at index of `0` and keep scroll at `item =1` , but when `insert(0,[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1])`, `list view` auto jump to `scrollOfset = 0` , `item = -5` ;

How to keep `scrollOffset` at `item = 1`, after `insert list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scroll_to_index](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index) package providing AutoScrollTag.

Comment: it is not available in this case, because there will be a jump from the value -5, to the value 0